# Form checkbox disappears when adding jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a Html form with checkboxes.

It seems that Whenever i add jQuery to the page those checkboxes disappears.

If i remove jQuery the checkboxes reappear but the form wont submit and just goes to a white screen.

- Its a Google docs custom form

I added jQuery like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried variants of jQuery versions, but it wont seem to help.

[The Webpage](http://www.tiesto.co.il/2.html)

What can cause this?

Comment: I'd work on fixing the errors first: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.tiesto.co.il%2F2.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Also check browser console for JS errors.

Comment: You already have JQuery 1.7.1 in your libraries.js. The checkboxes have been explicitly set to `opacity: 0` using JS.

Comment: Your right, eliminating the 1.8 ver' seems to work, but where can i find the opacity for the checkboxes?

Comment: nm found it..thank you for your help guys

Comment: In custom.js you are using jQuery onDocumentReady function ($(document).ready()). In this function you are calling the uniform_init() function which I believe is hiding the checkboxes. Please note that custom.js requires jQuery to function properly(this means you have to load jQuery before custom.js). You can start there, and figure out how uniform() works.

Comment: for some reason, when changing the checkbox opacity from 0 to 1 in library.js.. it throws the text to the bottom of the checkbox..how come?